# Match ID with Array number and assign key knockout js

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

So I have an array called domains which returns a variation of data, among which is a category spanding from 0-12.

It looks something like:

```
domains: {

0 {
available   :   true

category    :   0
}

1 {
available   :   true

category    :   1
}

2 {
available   :   true

category    :   2
}

3 {
available   :   true

category    :   3
}

4 {
available   :   true

category    :   4
}

}
```

Then I have the following keys:

```
categoryLabels {

0   :   Professional

1   :   Government

2   :   Finance

3   :   Business

4   :   Colors

}
```

Now what I would like to do is to display the matchin category with the matching categoryLabel

I have tried this but it doesnt seem to work:

```
  for (key in this.categoryLabels) {
                var item = {
                    name: key,         // Push the key on the array
                    value: this.categoryLabels[key] // Push the key's value on the array
                };
               return this.categoryName;
               console.log(this.categoryName.value);
            }
```

Does anyone have a solution ?

Comment: Your `categoryLabels` is not an array. You can't `forEach` over objects, even if they kind of look like arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tweaked your sample data assuming you are having a valid Data .

**view:**

```
<div data-bind="foreach:dom.domains">
  <p> available</p> : <b data-bind="text:available"></b>
  <p> category </p> : <b data-bind="text:ctgry.categoryLabels[category]">  
</div>
```

**code:**

```
var dom = {
  'domains': [{
    'available': true,'category': 0}, {'available': true, 'category': 1 },{'available': true,'category': 2  },{ 'available': true,'category': 3},{'available': true,  'category': 4
  }]
};

var ctgry = {
  'categoryLabels': { 0: 'Professional',1: 'Government', 2: 'Finance',3: 'Business',4: 'Colors',
  }
}

ko.applyBindings({ //pass your json data here 
  dom,
  ctgry
});
```

sample fiddle up for **[grabs](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/28975/)**

**PS:** Instead of passing json data directly to `ko`,however you can have your viewModel created and store it in observable & bind to view.

Comment: Thanks ! This seems to have fixed it.